# Finding out if two events are independent

Tags: probability, independence

The problem that I'm presented with is:

An insurance company is trying to attract new clients by offering new life and health insurance packages. The company has analyzed all of their clients (both old and new) that would buy some of the new packages. They concluded that out of all of their clients, 90% of them purchased a health insurance package and 30% of them purchased a life insurance package. The old clients make up for 70% of all their customers. The probability of a new client buying a life insurance package is 8/9, and the probability of a new client buying a health insurance package is 3/9.

1. If a randomly selected client is new, what is the probability that the client has purchased both of the insurance packages?
2. What is the probability of a randomly selected client being an old one, if we know that they purchased both of the insurance packages?

This is what I have come up with so far:

$$ H_{1}: \text{The client is an old one} $$

$$ H_{2}: \text{The client is a new one} $$

$$ A: \text{The client has purchased a health insurance package} $$

$$ B: \text{The client has purchased a life insurance package} $$

From the details given in the problem we have:

$$ P(H_{1}) = 0.7 $$

$$ P(H_{2}) = 0.3 $$

$$ P(A) = 0.9 $$

$$ P(B) = 0.3 $$

$$ P(A | H_{2}) = 3/9 $$

$$ P(A | H_{2}) = 8/9 $$

Now, the main problem that I have is that I'm not sure how to find out if the events A and B are independent or not. For question 1, I have set up the solution as:

$$ P(AB | H_{2}) =  \frac{P(ABH_{2})}{P(H_{2})} $$

Since I'm not sure if A and B are independent events or not, I don't know how to calculate the value for $ P(AB) $ and subsequently $ P(ABH_{2}) $

For question 2, I have calculated the probabilities of $ P(H_{2} | A) $ and $ P(H_{2} | B) $ with the help of the Bayes theorem, but to calculate $ P(H_{2} | AB) $ I need to know the value of $ P(AB) $.

So my questions are:

a) How do I know if A and B are independent?

b) Is my approach for the solution of the problem so far correct or do I need to change something?

Comment: Why should $A,B$ be independent?  After all, every client has to have bought at least one of the policies, no?

Comment: @lulu They don't have to be independent, but if they were, I would know how to calculate $ P(AB) $. If they are not independent I am not sure how I can calculate the value for $ P(AB) $. That's why I was wondering if there's a way I can know they're independent.

Comment: You have all the information you need to calculate the size of each possible cohort (new/both policies, old/life only, etc.)

Comment: @lulu Would you like to elaborate on how I can calculate $ P(AB|H_{2}) $ ?

Comment: There are three types of new client:  Those that bought only life, those that bought only health, and those that bought both.  Since $\frac 89$ of them either bought only life or both we must have $\frac 19$ who bought only health.  Then $\frac 29$ bought both and $\frac 69$ bought only life.

Comment: In general: $\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid H_n) = \mathsf P(A\mid H_n)+\mathsf P(B\mid H_n)-\mathsf P(A\cup B\mid H_n)$, and because $A\cup B$ is certain for any cohort, we have :$$\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid H_n) = \mathsf P(A\mid H_n)+\mathsf P(B\mid H_n)-1$$